# Average number of edges per voronoi cell in Additively Weighted voronoi diagram

Tags: analysis, graph-theory, computational-geometry, voronoi-diagram

It is proved that average number of edges per voronoi cell in **Voronoi diagram** is < 6. But can we say the same about the **Additive voronoi diagram** (variation of voronoi diagram)?

I have this doubt because in Additive voronoi diagram there can be hidden sites. Hence, we cannot claim that there can be (n+1) faces. Then what can we say about average number of edges per voronoi cell of additive voronoi diagram.

Comment: It must depend on the weight distribution. If we have an extreme power-law distribution we should expect one cell to entirely dominate diagram and exclude all others, while for an even distribution it is the usual distribution. So we need some kind of function from distribution to expected number of edges.